# Gostaria de saber como posso fazer um select com todas as sextas-feiras do ano no mysql por exemplo

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, fullcalendar

Estou desenvolvendo um calendario, e ele vai ser utilizado para marcar reuniões. Existem setores, como o setor de T.I por exemplo, que tem reunião todas as sextas-ferias, das 9:30 as 11:30, durante o ano todo. Preciso de alguma maneira, inserir na minha tabela "data de inicio" (da reunião), todas as sextas-feiras do ano.

Estou utilizando a biblioteca fullCalendar.io, mysql e PHP. Por favor, alguem me da uma luz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode construir um algorítimo que obtém todas as sexta-feiras do ano e depois inserir as datas no banco de dados. Segue um exemplo em PHP que obtém as datas:

```
<?php
# Ano a qual deseja obter todas as sexta-feiras.
$ano = 2018;

# Iniciamos a variável data com o primeiro dia do ano.
$data = new DateTime("$ano-01-01 08:30");

# Pecorremos todo o ano para encontrar todas as sexta-feiras.
while ($data->format('Y') == $ano)
{
    # Se sexta-feira
    if ($data->format('w') == 5) 
    {
        # Data sexta-feira.
        echo $data->format('Y-m-d H:i');

        # Depois que descobrimos a primeira sexta-feira do ano. Basta adicionar 7 dias a data
        # para encontrar a próxima sexta feira.
        $data->add(new DateInterval('P7D'));
    } 
    else 
    {
        # Caso a data inicial não seja uma sexta. Adiciona mais uma dia a data.
        $data->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado brother !!!!

Comment: Mais uma pergunta, se não for abusar muito. Como eu adicionaria o horario de 08:30 por exemplo?

Comment: @DiegoMarcelo Alterei para a data ficar com o horário de 08:30 fixo. Basta informar o horário na data inicial. E na hora de obter a data formatada adicionar a mascara para exibir hora e minutos.

Comment: Valeu mais uma vez!